# JavaScript object with Symbol property get's removed by Stringify

Tags: javascript, json

I'm attempting to send a React component tree via express and my array of components includes the critical `$$typeof: Symbol.for('react.element')` property. I'm using `res.send`. The rest of the object comes through except for that property. I've been advised it may have to do with Symbol.for not being enumerable? `JSON.stringify` also strips the property.

I've narrowed the issue down to being properties that have `Symbol` values. This is reflected [in the documentation for `stringify`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). Can anyone explain why that's the case or what a workaround is?

```js
const obj1 = {
  'stringKey': Symbol.for('String Value'),
  boolKey: true,
  numKey: 1
}

const obj2 = {...obj1, 'stringKey': 'Plain String'}

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj1))
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj2))
```

Comment: Hmm, marshaling whole tree of components is not something I have seen before. In most cases, the state or other objects, which determines said tree is what is serialized across the wire. In terms of architecture, is this a hard requirement?

Comment: I'm making it up as I go. I'm trying out this tool https://github.com/cerebral/marksy and so I am parsing a markdown file on the server and then sending the parsed content to the client and rendering from there.

Comment: Oh I see, well your looking to for server side rendering? Well in that case you should be using the output of `renderToString`. See the docs and even if your not using redux this tutorial has some good info, http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the symbol is used as value you could use custom `replacer` that formats Symbol to a string you could restore on receiving side using custom `reviver`

```js
const obj1 = {
  'stringKey': Symbol.for('String Value'),
  boolKey: true,
  numKey: 1
}

const obj2 = {...obj1, 'stringKey': 'Plain String'}

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj1, (name, value) => {
     if(typeof value === 'symbol') {
        value = `$$${Symbol.keyFor(value)}`
     }
     return value
}))
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj2))
```

Naive demo. You could better whilelist props that should be restored as symbols from registry.

```js
const a = {a: Symbol.for('a')}
const str = JSON.stringify(a, (k,v) => typeof v === 'symbol' ? `$$Symbol:${Symbol.keyFor(v)}` : v)
const b = JSON.parse(str, (k,v) => {
  const matches = v.match && v.match(/^\$\$Symbol:(.*)$/)
  return matches ? Symbol.for(matches[1]) : v
})

console.log(a, str, b, a.a === b.a)
```