# JavaScript object with Symbol key get's removed by Stringify, also can't iterate that

Tags: javascript, json

I'm working with Sequelize orm module. It's great module for orm. But on the where option there is something a bit wired.

```
const option = { where: { name: { [Op.like]: `%${name}%` } } }
const result = await model.findOne(option)
```

As you can see above code the `name` property has object `Op.like` as a key. I have checked the codebase of Sequelize's `Op`, so found that it's the `Symbol`. The `Op.like` is just `Symbol.for('like')`.

Of course that's no problem of using orm itself, but my problem is in stringify the `option` as json. The result of `Json.stringify` is just following (the Symbol key-value is removed):

```
{"where":{"name":{}}}
```

I have to save all history of `where` query and reuse that later, but haven't any solution of that.
Researched many stringify libraries such as [circular-json](https://github.com/WebReflection/circular-json) or [json-stringify-safe](https://github.com/moll/json-stringify-safe), but still same problem.
Also have read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45152582/javascript-object-with-symbol-property-gets-removed-by-stringify), but it's the case of `value` with Symbol, not `key`.
And tried to use custom replacer but can't iterate that too.

```
JSON.stringify(option, (key, value) => {
  if(typeof key === 'symbol') {
    console.log('symbol key: ', key) // nothing detected here
  }
  return value
})
```

Please help me any suggestion.

Comment: would using `[Op.like.description]` help?

Comment: From MDN's `JSON.stringify` docs: "All Symbol-keyed properties will be completely ignored, even when using the replacer function." Working as designed. What is your desired output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, symbol keys are specifically excluded from `JSON.stringify` (or rather, [any keys](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-json.stringify) that throw an error during their `ToString`, as Symbols [do](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tostring)). So the only way for them to show up in `JSON.stringify` is to replace them with string keys.

```js
function desymbolize(o) {
  if (Array.isArray(o)) {
    return o.map(desymbolize);
  } else if (typeof o != "object") {
    return o;
  } else {
    let d = Object.assign(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(o)), o);
    Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(o).forEach(k => {
      d[`<${Symbol.keyFor(k)}>`] = o[k];
      delete d[k];
    });
    Object.keys(d).forEach(k => d[k] = desymbolize(d[k]));
    return d;
  }
}

const Op = { like: Symbol.for('like') };
const option = { where: [{ name: { [Op.like]: `Amadan` } }] }
const desymOption = desymbolize(option);
console.log(JSON.stringify(desymOption)); // {"where":[{"name":{"<like>":"Amadan"}}]}
```

Comment: Awesome! You saved my times. :) So the solution of iterating symbols is `getOwnPropertySymbols` function.

Comment: There are a couple issue with this function. The first is that `typeof null` is `"object"`. The second is that it does not handle object reference cycles.